# Java8 Streams accumulator

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Trying to create an accumulator for a list, for example

```
public List<Double> accumulator(List<Double> originalList){
  List result = new ArrayList<>();
    Iterator<Double> iterator = originalList.iterator();
    double sum = 0;
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        sum = iterator.next() + sum;
        result.add(sum);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Im trying to convert this into using Streams API,
the only way i can think is starting by doing some partition and
than sum the results.

input [20,15,25]

partitions:

[20]    = 20

[20,15] = 35

[20,15,25] = 60

final result:
[20,35,60]

Any insights?

Comment: My goal is a list with accumulated values, for example, if the input List as 10,20,30 the resulting accumulation would be 10,30,60.

Comment: well i started with the code above, and taught about using the IntStream.range(0, size) to create several partitions using  ArrayList(originalList.subList(0,i) and then i could use reduce, but failed to create the partitions so far

Comment: i know there is partition in Streams but it uses predicates and not a index.

Comment: Well, you can't use reduce, it makes a single value.  I think map is what you want.  You should put the code up that you have written, along with its output.

Comment: yes i was trying something like IntStream.range(0, size).map(
                i -> new ArrayList(originalList.subList(0,i))
        );

Comment: Per the link to the duplicate, `Arrays.parrallelPrefix()` is recommended here, which kind of sucks because it's a static method **and** returns `void`.  Here's my code: `int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3 };  Arrays.parallelPrefix( arr, (s, e) -> s + e );`